# onblur taking last clicked value not taking current clicked value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, onblur

I am using onblur event to get the value of date in datepicker. Here is my control:

```html
<input placeholder="MM/DAY/YEAR" data-bind="value: CustomerBookingTbl.PickUpDate" class="input date" name="pickupdate" onblur="UpdatePrice(this)" type="text" required>
```

and here is my function:

```js
function UpdatePrice(_this)
{
    console.log(_this.value);
}
```

When I clicked on 06/07/2017 then it takes null. Afterward, I clicked on  06/07/2017 then it takes **06/06/2017** as a value.

I am attaching the image also 
[image: console.log showing dates]

Comment: the blur is firing because you click on a datepicker - but the datepicker click event happens after the blur on the input, therefore the input hasn't changed yet - surely the datepicker has some hooks into which you can insert your code instead

Comment: what `datepicker` plugin you are using?

Comment: <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
this one

Comment: You can use onchange method as well so it will give you proper output in console like <input placeholder="MM/DAY/YEAR" data-bind="value: CustomerBookingTbl.PickUpDate" class="input date" name="pickupdate" onchange="UpdatePrice(this)" type="text" required>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out events provided by [datePicker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html)

> Datepicker triggers a number of events in certain circumstances. All
>   events have extra data attached to the event object that is passed to
>   any event handlers

You could use this event to track [changeDate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate) event of date

> **changeDate**
>
> Fired when the date is changed.

```
$("YOUR_DATE_PICKER").on("changeDate", function(e) {
    //// `e` here contains the extra attributes
    alert('hey');
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfjz280v/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one as well

```
<input placeholder="MM/DAY/YEAR" data-bind="value: CustomerBookingTbl.PickUpDate" class="input date" name="pickupdate" onchange="UpdatePrice(this)" type="text" required>

<script>
function UpdatePrice(_this) {           
  console.log(_this.value);
}
</script>
```

Its quite easy solution

Live demo : https://jsfiddle.net/jalayoza/pyc1vp19/3/

Hope this helps